# What mean Models in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to create a RESTful API with PHP and tutorial I found is: http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/ and everything worked pretty well only in a part of the tutorial did not understand something.

Near the end of the tutorial, when you create a script to run the API does the following:

```
$Apikey = new Models\APIkey();
$User = new Models\User();
```

I do not understand what the "`new Models\Whatever();`" someone could advise me a bit about it and how it works?

In advance I thank you very much.

Comment: You mean namespaces? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Yes elclanrs, I thought the word "Models" was a reserved word and had a specific use. But now you have made me see that was really a namespace and I'm reading a bit of it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aside from the badly worded question, it's not a bad question so I'm not sure what all the abuse in the comments are about.

That syntax is just instantiating a class as normal - the classes in this case being `APIKey` and `User`. The only difference is that these classes are in a [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) (`Models`). You must refer to your class within the namespace it belongs to.

Generally when writing PHP without namespaces, everything exists in the base namespace, so you can refer to classes within the current namespace by just their names. If you have `namespace Models` written at the top of your page, you can refer to those two classes in your example as just `APIKey` or `User`.

If you are within a namespace, and want to instantiate a class that is in the base namespace, you can do this:

```
namespace Models

$api = new \Api();
```

Similar to file systems, the preceding `\` just refers back to the base namespace.

Comment: Yes, I think you understood me better than others. That's what I did not know what the "namespaces" had never seen or used in PHP also think I have formulated the question wrong because I know very little English :(

Thank you very much!